# How to let color of svg and span text color same

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

Here is my Vue code:

```
      <icon
          :color="itemDynamicColor"
          :data="icon"
      />
      <span v-bind:style="dynamicStyle">SpanText</span>
```

I want the icon and span text keep same color, as you see, I use computed property to define icon color and span color. However I think this way is a little stupid.

I wonder if there is any better way?

## EDIT

Actually the color of both will change when some data change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The color of both will change when some data change.*

To achieve this, you can update the `dynamicStyle` object in both `<icon>` and `<span>` based on the condition as per your requirement.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dynamicColor: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <!-- For icon you can apply same dynamicColor property dynamically -->
  <span :style="dynamicColor">SpanText</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this all in plain CSS by using a custom property for the color you want, and then setting the color of the `<icon>` and `<span>` to that.

Comment: Thanks. However the color will change. (see my update

Comment: Then (from my limited Vue knowledge), I think your way is potentially the best.